# How can I automatically merge updated changes from a repository to my trunk?

Tags: svn, merge

I have a local branch that I periodically want to merge any updates from an open source repository into.

I know you can specify range of revisions to merge using:

```
svn merge -rN:M [Source] [Destination]
```

Is there a way to auto pick up the updated changes that I haven't merged yet? (AKA maybe just specify the start revision and pick up everything to the latest without having to know the last revision.)

Comment: In svn there is no such thing as a "local branch". What are you really doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running SVN 1.8, just omit the revision arguments.  This performs a ["sync" merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync), and SVN determines which revisions have and have not already been merged into your destination using the [`svn:mergeinfo`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo) properties.

So, to make a short story shorter, run:

```
svn merge [Source] [Destination]
```